# How can I parse this JSON Pokemon Dictionary? (swift 3)

Tags: json, parsing, dictionary, swift3

I have an issue with parsing JSON data from new version of the Pokemon API, specifically with values of the "defense" and the"attack".

In Pokemon API v1 it was easy...

```
//JSON:
"attack": 45,
"defense": 65

//After parsing in Alamofire i'm got the next solution:
if let dict = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let attack = dict["attack"] as? Int {
                self._attack = attack
            }

            if let defense = dict["defense"] as? Int {
                self._defense = defense
            }
            print(self._attack)
            print(self._defense)
```

In Pokemon API v2 i have **an issue with JSON format**:

```
//JSON:
"stats": [

    {
        "stat": {
            "url": "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/3/",
            "name": "defense"
        },
        "effort": 0,
        "base_stat": 45
    },
    {
        "stat": {
            "url": "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/",
            "name": "attack"
        },
        "effort": 0,
        "base_stat": 65
    }
]
```

I have tried this option, but it doesn't work:

```
 if let stats = dict["stats"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>], stats.count > 0 {
         if let stat = stats[0]["stat"] as? Dictionary<String, String>{
                    if name = stat["defense"] {
                      if let defense = stats[0]["base_stat"] as? Int {
                            self._defense = defense
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    }
       print(self._defense)
```

Please advise, how can I parse and get the value of "defense" correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line `if name = stat["defense"] {` your `JSON` has key `name` and `defense` & `attack` are its value, so you need to get its value and need to check is it `defense` or `attack`.

```
if name = stat["name"] as? String, name == "defense" {

}
```

You can also reduce the code of getting `base_stat` with single `if let` like this.

```
if name = stat["name"] as? String, let score = stats[0]["base_stat"] as? Int, name == "defense" {
     print("defense : \(score)")
}
```

Comment: Simple and clear answer, understandable for beginner, thanks for help.

Comment: Honestly, i would accept both answers, as they both are good, each in its own way, it is a pity that it is impossible.

Comment: @Rurom You can accept any answer you want, what i'm saying is that you are facing issue with your old code because you are accessing wrong key instead of correct one and that is suggest by me :)

Comment: Absolutely right, you precisely specified my mistake and helped, i appreciate it. Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
guard let statsNode = dict["stats"] as? [[String: Any]] else { return }

for (index, statNode) in statsNode.enumerated() {

    guard let statValue = statNode["base_stat"] as? Int else { continue }

    switch index {
        case 0:
            self._defense = statValue
        case 1:
            self._attack = statValue
        case 2:
            self._someStat = statValue
        ....
        default:
            break
    }

}
print(self._attack)
print(self._defense)
```

I've worked on a similar project when I started out in iOS Development.
These days I prefer guard let statements over if let statements when parsing JSON for information that's required in my project

I'm also assuming since the stats node is an array, the order of attack, defense, special attack, special defense, speed and HP won't change so the switch statement is an appropriate tool to use in this case.

It might also be helpful to put a print statement before return and continue in the guard statements' else block to see if you hit those else blocks in the program.

Comment: I'm just a beginner in Swift, your solution looks very professional, it's new knowledge for me, thanks for good advice.

Comment: Glad I could help! We all start somewhere. My advice is look into guard and switch statements. They are very useful in JSON parsing